Setting variables based on screen title, is it possible? (using javascript via code.org for a project)
I have an app on code.org that uses multiple screens, and for the buttons that I use to navigate them, I find myself writing the same onEvent, only different each time.
The first would go as follows:
onEvent("nextButton1", "click", function(){
   setScreen("person1");
});

Then, for a button on the next screen, with the same exact appearance AND purpose, the coding goes as follows:
onEvent("nextButton2", "click", function(){
   setScreen("person2");
});

When I noticed this pattern (somewhat a redundancy when you consider just how similar they are), I figured "I should be able to set a variable (i) that is equal to 1, and then when you hit the next Button for a screen, that variable would increase by one. This way, the same variable name could be used, while it created an incrementally larger value after each button was pressed.
So, I created the following code:
var i = 1;

onEvent("button" + i, " click", function(){
   setScreen("person" + i);
   i++; //If i didn't use this, it would be i = i + 1
});`

This ended up working for just screen one, and I came to discover that that was because "i" is a global variable, so it essentially trumps over the change that occurs at the end of the onEvent. You might think "why can't you just put it inside the onEvent to make it a local one?" I can't because if I did that, then the onEvent would no longer have a defined id to be called by. In other words, if i don't establish i BEFORE the onEvent, the id ("button" + i) is undefined/invalid.
So, my final question is: is there a way to create or use a function that IDENTIFIES which screen that I'm on, so that I can set the variable (i) BASED on that information. I know this is a mouthful but I would really appreciate it.
To make sure that whoever is reading this gets the clarification they might need about what i'm trying to do: my goal is to set up a conditional based on the screen, so that then i can be established. For example:
if(getScreen) == "homeScreen"{
 i = 1
}else if(getScreen) == "user1"{
i=2
}else if(getScreen) == "user2"{
i=3..... 

and so on and so forth.
your text

I suspect that your real question might be, "If I have an expression like person + i in a lambda function where i is determined outside of the  lambda function, when will that expression be evaluated?" If the expression doesn't get evaluated until the button is pressed, it's too late for you. You're trying to pass the same function to several different onEvent calls but you want the parameter value passed to setScreen to be different for each event.

So, you either want a generic function which you can instantiate with different values of person + i or you want a way to detect the event source ie the name of the button that was actually clicked to trigger the event, from which you can derive the screen name.

Correct. To be more specific, I'd prefer the latter: a way to detect the event source. Is there some kind of code that can be written to do such a thing?
